# Integral representation of Zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

Currently studying Complex Analysis and was baffled by the following
$$
\Gamma(s) \zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(s)}{n^{s}}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t} t^{s-1}}{n^{s}} \mathrm{d} t=\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n t} t^{s-1} \mathrm{d} t
$$

How does one obtain the right hand side from the equation before it?

Comment: Change the integration variable from $t$ to $n x$ and then call the $x$ as $t$.

Comment: @Gary Doesn't work

Comment: It does work: $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - nx} (nx)^{s - 1} }}{{n^s }}} (ndx)}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - nx} n^s x^{s - 1} }}{{n^s }}} dx}  \\ = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {e^{ - nx} x^{s - 1} } dx}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {e^{ - nt} t^{s - 1} } dt} .$$

Comment: @Gary Didn't do it correctly, my bad. Also, one more question, I'm assuming we can make this substitution because the integral and summation can be exchanged, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I should have written it like that. One does the substitution before actually moving the summation inside the integral.

Comment: @Gary Thanks! If you want to write it out and i'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to derive the formula is
\begin{align*}
\Gamma (s)\zeta (s) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma (s)}}{{n^s }}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_0^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - t} \frac{{t^{s - 1} }}{{n^s }}\mathrm{d}t} }&\, \mathop  = \limits^{t = nx} \,\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_0^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - nx} x^{s - 1}\, \mathrm{d}x} } \\ &\;\, = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\mathrm{e}^{ - nx} } x^{s - 1} \,\mathrm{d}x} .
\end{align*}

Comment: How to justify the inversion of sum and integral?

Comment: @Julien Use Tonelli's theorem or the monotone convergence theorem. A sum with positive terms can always be integrated term-wise.

Comment: Here the sequence is complex

Comment: @Julien Assume $s>1$ and use analytic continuation in the end to extend the result to $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$.